# How do I find the base address of "NOR Flash/PSRAM/SRAM/ROM/LCD 1" on a STM32H743?

Tags: stm32, fmc, stm32h743

With the STM32F427, the generated code included a couple of different #defines which mapped to the address to which I needed to write:

e.g.

```
#define FMC_BANK3_BASE  ((uint32_t)(0x60000000 | 0x08000000))
```

Where can I find similar #defines in a CubeMX generated project for the STM32H743?  (I think I need FMC_BANK1 here.)

I'm looking for the address at which the memory/lcd is mapped, not the address of the controller registers (which I already have).

Comment: have you checked memory mapping in the reference manual ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I couldn't find any appropriate #defines, [reading the manual I found](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/c9/a3/76/fa/55/46/45/fa/DM00314099/files/DM00314099.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00314099.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A4387%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C124%2C753%2Cnull%5D):

> Figure 95. FMC memory banks (default mapping)

This showed that `Bank 1` is located at `0x6000 0000`, as it is on the stm32f413.

Comment: In order to not get 4 writes when you expect 1, you need to swap the banks, or change the memory properties of the block at 0x6000 0000.  See: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWQE/stm32h743ii-fmc-8080-lcd-spurious-writes